# Determine Usage of Azure Hosted Agents

Tags: azure-devops, azure-agent

I am looking for a way to find out how much my Hosted Agents have been used (in hours) for a week/month. Do you know a way to do so? Is there an REST-API Endpoint I could use or can you recommend an extension which would be helpfull?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the endpoint is:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

Or

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}?api-version=6.0
```

HTTP verb: **GET**

Example usage in BASh:

```
organization="your-organization"
project="your-project"
agentPoolId="your-agent-pool-id"

curl -u username:password "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/distributedtask/pools/$agentPoolId?api-version=6.0"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I use the endpoints you suggest, I dont get any information about the time usage of the agents. Or infomration that would help me to retireve that information. ![Valid XHTML](https://imgur.com/a/W3ONMLt)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Azure DevOps REST API.
Have a look at this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/pools/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1

This API allows you to get a list of build and release runs, including their duration. There are also Azure DevOps extensions available in the Visual Studio Marketplace that might provide more user-friendly reporting or integrate with other analytics tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension [Build usage](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.BuildandTestUsage). It can show how many build minutes are being used within an account and make them visible for your team by adding Build Usage tiles to your dashboard.

My test screenshoot:

[image]

[image]

[image]